# Define list view with static elements on android in xml?

Tags: android-layout

I want to create fragment which would display static menu as a set of rows in a list.

I like iOS method with static cells in a tableview. How can I achieve this in android (so no code is needed to define elements, just xml)

Is there any regular way to define static elements in xml next way

(pseudo-code)

```
list_view.xml

<List view>
  - use element my_row with onclick=row1_clicked and title="row 1"
  - use element my_row with onclick=row2_clicked and title="row 2"
  - use element my_row with onclick=row3_clicked and title="row 3"
  - use element my_row with onclick=row4_clicked and title="row 4"
</List view>

my_row.xml

<My Row>
  - text field (title should go here)
  - on click (on click should go here)
</My Row>
```

So basically I want to "include" row in list and do it on xml level (without code).

Comment: I have no idea why someone downvoted this question, because I had the same question. So +1 to compensate for the downvote and because I came here looking for an answer to exactly this question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unfortunately, list view definition via xml is forbidden. Mess with adapters is required instead.

Comment: I can't believe how far Android API lags behind Microsoft in terms of GUI design. Their XML based stuff is just so much better.

Comment: @rTECH Nothing new

Answer (score 25):

Some progress can be made using a string-array, e.g.,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
  <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/sports_array"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

couple with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string-array name="sports_array">
    <item>Shuttle Badminton</item>
    <item>Tennis</item>
    <item>FootBall</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

source: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-creating-and-populating-listview-items-in-xml/

Comment: If I use android:entries, how can I customize my rows layouts? Thanks

Comment: @Ricardo, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Ricardo, this works only with string List views. If you want to use custom layouts, for each item in the list, it is preferable to use adapters or the approach suggested in [David Viehtauer's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31456900/3676145)

Answer (score 15):

You can use a vertical LinearLayout nested within a ScrollView to get what you're looking for. Put your "listview" items inside the LinearLayout, and style them to look like elements of a listview.

If you absolutely must use a ListView (e.g. you're using ListFragment), you'll have to use a ListAdapter subclass or roll your own.

Answer (score 6):

Actually there is a way!
Re-using Layouts with **include** - Tag

Simply define a Layout you want to reuse.

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lena" />
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/profileOnline"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Then include it in your ViewGroup as many times as required

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

You can also override all the layout parameters (any android:layout_* attributes) of the included layout's root view by specifying them in the  tag. For example:

```
<include android:id="@+id/news_title"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         layout="@layout/title"/>
```

More information at http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html