# Single column list of images from drawable folder, only using XML

Tags: android, xml, listview, xml-drawable

Is it possible to create a scrolling listview of images that are stored in the drawable folder, only with XML?

Before, I had a ListView in my XML with each drawable in its own ImageView. I've found solutions using adapters and classes in Java, but is there an XML only solution?

I have built this string-array, where "picture1.png" is one of the images in my drawable folder.

```
<string-array name="mylistofpictures">
    <item>picture1</item>
    <item>picture2</item>
    <item>picture3</item>
    ...
    <item>picture99</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate][1]

Look at the bottom answer (not the selected one).

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864260/define-list-view-with-static-elements-on-android-in-xml

Comment: @airowe The solution in your link appears to only return the text from the array (i.e "picture1" as a list item, instead of the actual image file).

Answer (score 0):

Create `string-array` in `string.xml` and find it in adapter class..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 ListView list;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
 }

 public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private String [] image;
    private Context context;

    public  MyAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;

        //-- here you are getting array from xml
        image= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array);  
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup   parent) {
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getIdentifier(image[position], "drawable", getPackageName()));
        return view;
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution requires Java; I'm looking for an XML only solution if it is possible. If not, I'd like to at least make use of my string-array as its contents are used in that format for other parts of my application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just use xml. Get the drawable ids from your R file and include those as values in your xml list or another xml list with matching indexes. Set the drawableid using the same index as your listview item and use setDrawable to set the image using id.